# three.js: Raytrace specific bones from JSON-based skinned mesh?

Tags: json, three.js, mesh, raytracing

I have a skinned mesh (imported from a JSON file). I'm trying to access its bones through raytracing and am (expectedly) only able to access the parent mesh itself.

Is there any way to discern which bone was hit by the raytracer? Does the raytracer traverse the children of the skeleton until it reaches a specific bone? If so, I found no indication of it.

If not, what would be the most efficient way (or really, any way) to raytrace to specific bones? Trying to get a bone click+drag UI happening and I'm out of ideas (except, possibly, invisible THREE.Object3d's near joints which would be a pain to implement - I have 75 bones...)

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you!